# Callback onLoad for React-Apollo 2.1

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

I want to know what's the best way to handle setting a parent's state when the Apollo `<Query>` component finishes loading? I have an id that I sometimes have to query for. I wonder what's the best way to handle this case?

Currently I have it where the child component will listen for prop changes and if I notice that the prop for the data I'm looking for changes I'll call a function to update the state.

Is there a better way to handle this without needing the child component to listen to updates?

This is a pseudo code of what I'm currently doing

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

class FolderFetcher extends React.Component<Props, { id: ?string}> { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: props.id
    }
  }

  setId = (id) => {
    this.setState({ id });
  };

  render() {
    const { id } = this.props;

    return (
      <Query skip={...} query={...}>
        ((data) => {
          <ChildComponent id={id} newId={data.id} setId={this.setId} />
        })
      </Query>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component<Props> {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.newId !== this.props.newId && 
        this.props.id !== this.props.newId) {
      this.props.setId(this.props.newId);
    }
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can export child as wrapped with HoC from apollo

```
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo'

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  // inside props you have now handy `this.props.data` where you can check for `this.props.data.loading == true | false`, initially it's true, so when you will assert for false you have check if the loading was finished. 
}

export default graphql(Query)(ChildComponent)
```

Another option would be to get client manually, and run `client.query()` which will return promise and you can chain for the `then()` method.